# How can I preserve posts protruding through a patio?

Tags: concrete, framing

I am having a patio poured where there was once a deck.  There are 2 large 8x8 posts on piers, and the posts will be about 3-4” below the new concrete surface.  They have concealed plate hardware securing them to the pier, about 1/2” above the top of the concrete, and cutting them above the new patio really isn’t an option.

My question is what is the best way to protect them from rot?  I was thinking put a form around them so the concrete doesn’t touch, then fill with gravel after.  Or wrap them in a barrier and pour the concrete right up to it.  There will be about 6” of gravel beneath them and drainage will be good.  Am I overthinking?  They are not treated posts, but are sealed, and have been in place for 16 years.  Thanks!

Comment: *Untreated wood 4" below the new surface.* You'll be **finding** an option to cut them above the new surface in a few years when you rot them out, so you might as well find that now and save yourself the bother later.

Comment: What are the 8x8 posts for? I presume they were for the deck that is now no longer there... so if that's the case, why exactly do you need to keep the posts?

Comment: You're pouring over the posts, and are trying to prevent them from rotting? Is that your intention?

Comment: What are the posts? If they're pressure-treated they're probably rated for ground contact anyway. There will be gravel beneath _what_? You said the posts rest on piers. Please revise to add enough detail for us to help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't drill, hack, and otherwise cut these posts at least down to ground level, so the pour will completely cover them? If they're no longer needed, don't let them complicate the project..

Comment: Why do you want to preserve?